# Is SFSpeechRecognizer able to return the result in pinyin?

Tags: swift, sfspeechrecognizer

Currently I'm using my `SFSpeechRecognizer` to detect spoken words in chinese what works pretty good so far. The result is given in chinese character, but is there a way to get the spoken words in pinyin as well?

I only know three different language codes for chinese: `zh-CN`, `zh-HK`, `zh-TWN`. But they all return chinese characters.